# My app is running on emulator and when I connect my real device with usb, but when I send apk file to my real device, app is crashing

Tags: android, flutter, crash, android-emulator, usb

I tried to send apk file to my real device without connecting my device. The app crashes constantly. So, I tried to connect my real device for debugging. The app is running without any problem.

If you have any idea, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project before to build your apk. In your terminal, type `flutter clean && flutter pub get`.

Also, check if the minsdkversion of your project is below the sdk version of your physical device.